# PHP 8.1 preg_replace only outside of two UBB tags - regex probably wrong

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace the line break `\n` or `\r` with the HTML tag `<br>`, but only outside of `[code]` UBB tags.

Example string, how it is stored in the DB:

```
$string = "Test 123
Line break
[code]5: Test
10: With line
15: breaks[/code]
Further writing
Another new line";
```

Using this code:

```
$bbextended = array(
"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\r?\\n/i" => "<br>",
"/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/i" => "<textarea>$1</textarea>",
);
foreach($bbextended as $match=>$replacement){
$string = preg_replace($match, $replacement, $string);
}
echo $string;
```

I end up with this HTML output:

```
Line break<br>Test123<br>[code]5: Test<br>10: With line<br>15: breaks[/code]<br>Further writing<br>Another new line
```

Which means that line breaks within the [code][/code] UBB tags were replaced with `<br>` (wrong, should not) and the code elements were not replaced by `<textarea></textarea>` (also wrong).

The expected HTML output is:

```
Line break<br>Test123<br><textarea>5: Test
10: With line
15: breaks
</textarea><br>Further writing<br>Another new line
```

I tried to solve it on my own with regex101, but it highlights stuff that shouldnt be highlighted..
[image: regex101]

I assume there is an issue caused by the actual line breaks and how regex searches.

Comment: See [`s` (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). Just change your pattern to [`/`... `/is`](https://regex101.com/r/5x8grZ/1). FYI: You can drop the capturing group and use `\R` for *any newline sequence* instead of `\r?\n`.

Answer (score 0):

`"/[code[\w\W]*?code](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\r?\\n/i" => "<br>",`

this seems to work - to detect start and end of my code tags across multiple lines and skip them from formatting with

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).